# Paint on Photoshop Layer and Alpha Channel with the Brush at the same time?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create a Image of a brush stroke with a perfect alpha channel, but using the tools in the Selection menu doesn't result in a too perfect result.

Since it's also possible to paint in the alpha channel, is it possible to paint onto a layer and onto the alpha channel at the same time, so it creates a perfect selection?

or am I just doing something wrong when trying to create an alpha channel of a little more complex brush strokes?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the brush stroke on its own layer, ctrl+click the layer and then create a new alpha channel from the selection.

Comment: thx horatio, but that option isn't available to me, only "create clipping mask"

Comment: On the Mac, it's Cmd-click (on the thumbnail image in the Layers Panel). Control-click is the equivalent of a right click in Mac OS.